# comparator with one to many relation filed

Tags: java, comparable

i have a DTO object ClientInfo that holds a List of document entity.

i use the following compare method to sort clientInfo list by documentCreationDate DESC.

```
    @Override
        public int compareTo(ClientInfo o) {

            Date firstmaxDate = this.getDocuments().stream().map(d -> d.getCreateDate()).max(Date::compareTo).get();
            Date secondmaxDate = o.getDocuments().stream().map(d -> d.getCreateDate()).max(Date::compareTo).get();
            return firstmaxDate.compareTo(secondmaxDate);

        }
List<ClientInfo> clientInfos= serverReturnedList......;
Collections.sort(clientInfos);
```

But its getting an exception telling that comparison rule has been violated.
so i m not getting the expected result. can anyone explain whats the way to achieve this.

This is the exception stack trace

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
        at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
        at com.orsbv.hcs.dto.ClientInfo.compareTo(ClientInfo.java:346)
        at com.orsbv.hcs.dto.ClientInfo.compareTo(ClientInfo.java:24)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
        at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
        at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
```

Comment: "not getting the expected result." What result are you getting? Is it not ordered at all, or ordered in reverse, or what?

Comment: What is the `Date` you are using? `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` or some other class?

Comment: First I would suggest you to rename `firstmaxDate` to `thisMaxDate` and then `secondmaxDate` to `otherMaxDate`, also if all `*CreateDate` are in the past they should follow the `*CreatedDate` pattern... Now I'm pretty sure you gave enough info for a person to start digging and find out what's wrong with your implementation still I will not do it as it will take me at least 10mins to get to that point.. If you want an answer then make the effort to provide all the vital data...

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: MC Emperor --stack trace posted with question

Comment: Prasad Karunagoda java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly i added a maxDocuemntCreationDate field to clientInfo.

```
  Date maxCreationDate = clientInfo.getDocuments()
                        .stream()
                        .map(Document :: getCreateDate)
                        .max(Date::compareTo)
                        .orElseGet(Date::new);
```

Then i compare in this fashion

```
 @Override
            public int compareTo(ClientInfo o) {


              return 
              this.getMaxCreationDate().compareTo(o.getMaxCreationDate());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your `compareTo()` method as it's written, because it's sorting according to natural ordering (ascending), which makes sense.

Instead you should change the sort, to tell it to sort in reverse (descending) order.

```
List<ClientInfo> clientInfoList = ...
Collections.sort(clientInfoList, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

UPDATE based on info added to question:

Some of your `ClientInfo` don't have any documents that you can use to check created date.

When you do this:

```
 Date firstmaxDate = this.getDocuments().stream().map(d -> d.getCreateDate()).max(Date::compareTo)
```

the `max()` returns an `Optional<Date>` which allows it to return `Optional.empty()` in the case of an empty stream. When you've a ClientInfo without any document, you're calling `get()` on an empty `Optional`, which causes this exception.

You need to determine whether this case can occur in the real data, and if so, how you want to sort ClientInfo with no document. If all your createdDates are in the past, you could simply replace "no created date" with "now":

```
        Date thisDate = this.getDocuments()
                .stream()
                .map(Document::getCreateDate)
                .max(Date::compareTo)
                .orElseGet(Date::new);
        Date otherDate = o.getDocuments()
                .stream()
                .map(Document::getCreateDate)
                .max(Date::compareTo)
                .orElseGet(Date::new);
```

Or, you could stop before `get()`, work with `Optional<Date>` and check for `isPresent()` and handle as needed.

Comment: thanks for your response.but my problem is sort() is not working.its getting an exception.@ Andrew Spencer